# Variable INT type receiving 0 regardless of typed number

Tags: c

I'm new here and kinda new to programming (specially C), and I'm facing a problem with a variable. The variable VAL1 receives its value from the first SCANF(), but after the second group of PRINTF()/SCANF() the value goes to 0 regardless of what I do.

What I'm doing wrong? Please have in mind that my knowledge of C is very superficial. This code is a excerpt of a another bigger code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int vagastot;

int main()
{
    int val1;
    char ch3;

    printf("\n  Type new value : ");
    scanf("%d", &val1);

    printf("\n  Confirm? (Y|N) : ");
    scanf("%s", &ch3);

    if(ch3=='Y' || ch3=='y')
    {
        vagastot = val1;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ch3` is only large enough to hold a single character. Did you mean to use `%c` with the second `scanf`?

Comment: and check the return value of scanf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format specifier in the second `scanf()` is incorrect and results in [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Since you are reading a single `char`, the format specifier should be `"%c"` rather than `"%s"`.

Comment: I have changed to "%c" on the second SCANF(), but now it doesn't let me input, and answer it automatically.

Comment: I've found what was the issue, I've placed a fflush(stdin) before the scanf() and now everything works fine.